# I'm trying to cURL this simple URL in PHP and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Tags: php, json, rest, curl, php-curl

I'm trying to cURL this URL and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'd really appreciate some help!

Here's my code (with my API Token taken out)

```
$url ='https://app.files.com/api/rest/v1/users/0.json'; 

$header = array("Accept: application/json, X-FilesAPI-Key: FakeKeyGoesHere");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 
1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
$retValue = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($retValue);
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What response you get?

Comment: I suspect you would need CA certs to be added to curl as well since your endpoint is `https`.

Answer (score 0):

there are two problems:

1. the `$header` is in incorrect form. it must be an array with one element per one header, but you have them alltogather in one string.

try

```
$header = array("Accept: application/json", "X-FilesAPI-Key: FakeKeyGoesHere");
```

2. do not use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");`, if the data comes in another encoding - the result will be mess. use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");` for input-encoding-autodetect.